# C++11 string initialization

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I need to create a string of 100 *A* characters.

Why does the following

```
std::string myString = {100, 'A'};
```

give different results than

```
std::string myString(100, 'A');
```

?

Comment: For universal initialization, simply replace '()' with '{}'.  You should be doing `std::string myString{100,'A'};`

Comment: @CrazyEddie but this is an example of where that change in brackets would radically change the behaviour of the program. The `initializer_list` constructor takes precedence over all others. The `=` sign makes no difference here. [See demo](http://ideone.com/VxAQUY).

Comment: @CrazyEddie How does that make a difference? The result is still not the same as `std::string myString(100, 'A');`

Comment: @juanchopanza - ugh.  OK.  Thanks for the _helpful_ correction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
std::string myString = {100, 'A'};
```

is initialization using initializer list. It creates a string with 2 characters: one with code 100 and 'A'

```
std::string myString(100, 'A');
```

calls the following constructor:

```
string (size_t n, char c);
```

which creates a string with 100 'A's

Comment: Formally, the first argument is merely a `char` with the value 100; it's ASCII if your system treats `char` values as ASCII. While that's quite common, it's not required by the C++ language definition, and there are systems where it's not true.

Comment: @Fanael - I don't know how hard it was, but it's an important point that is often overlooked, and merely editing the text doesn't remind people of it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Does that mean that `std::string s = { 100, 'A' };` is undefined behaviour? Wouldn't that invalidate most of the intention of creating the uniform initializer syntax in C++11?

Comment: @DanielFrey: it's not UB. `CHAR_MAX` is required to be at least 127, so 100 is a valid value of `char` regardless of what glyph it represents (if any -- not all values of `char` necessarily represent characters at all, so in theory you might have trouble *printing* it).

Comment: @DanielFrey - `char` is an arithmetic type as well as a character representation; there's nothing wrong with assigning 100 to a `char` object.

Answer (score 1):

The first initializes it to values of 100 and `A` and the second calls a constructor overload of `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, that constructor would give you a string with 100 `'A'` characters.